# This 'v-if' should be moved to the wrapper element (vue/no-use-v-if-with-v-for)

Tags: vue.js

I am getting lint error using v-if and v-for. What would be best way to resolve it?

```
 <div>
   <input class="input is-static"
   type="text"
   v-model="userId"
   readonly
   v-if=" type === 'Admin'" />
   <div class="buttons">
     <button v-if="type !== 'Admin'"
     v-for="(option, index) in users" :key="index">
     {{ option }}
     </button>
    </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: move the `v-if` to the `div class='buttons'` element like the error tells you to?

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

you can't use v-if in the same html element with a v-for do you need move the v-if to some parent element wrapping your button.

I would have written something like this in your case

```
<div v-if="type !== 'Admin'">
  <input v-model="userId" class="input is-static" type="text" readonly />
  <div class="buttons">
    <button
      v-for="(option, index) in users" :key="index">
      {{ option }}
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```